# How to track offline transactions for Firebase iOS in Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Apps I'm using `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` with `firebaseReference.keepSynced(true)` on specific childs.

But in the Firebase documentation it states that transactions are not persisted across app restarts if the App has been offline:

[image]

Is there a delegate or observer or anything else that tells me *what* transactions have failed so that I an follow the best practice suggestion by Firebase and store them on a local offline database?

I'm not getting an object that tells me wether or not the transaction failed, or did not fail?

```
open func uploadObject<T: ClientObject>(of type: T.Type, with firebaseQuery: FirebaseQuery, object: T, completion: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil) {

    let query = firebaseQuery.queryPath
    let path = firebaseQuery.firebasePath.getPath(with: query, subPath: firebaseQuery.subPath)
    let prefix = firebaseQuery.firebasePath.prefix

    let serialized = object.serialized

    let child = path + prefix + object.uuid

    if object.uuid.isEmpty {

        let message = Log.Message.uuidMissing("Object UUID is empty for: \(child) object: \(serialized) at: \(#file), \(#function)")
        Log.notify(message)
    }

    self.reference.child(child).setValue(serialized) { error, _ in

        Log.error(error, at: #function, line: #line)
        completion?(error)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no callbacks or delegates for transactions that are wiped when the user goes offline. If you want your app to handle offline situations gracefully, you should not rely on transactions in your code.

Comment: So what would be another option then? How would I get data to firebase then? Check for online status and only then push otherwise rely on offline db?

Comment: If you want it to work offline, don't use transactions. Instead use append-only/idempotent data structure. For example: say you have a banking system. Instead of using a transaction to update the balance from every client, instead push each transfer (change in money) into the database. Then to calculate the current balance, read the starting balance and all unresolved transactions. You'll want to in that case also periodically write back an updated balance and resolving all transactions, which you can do when you detect that the system is connected to the database.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this answer. I will see how I can incorporate those thoughts.